# How to extend Access Management Access Token life time automatically

Tags: sites-9.6, access-management

We are using Access Management with SDL 9.6. while using the CMS, after some time(approx 30min) it's shown "connection Closed" Message on brower. we are unable to open cms in subsequent browser tabs as well. if we open cms url on Incognito only, we are able to access the CMS again.

Is there any way to extend token life time automatically? why we are getting error continuiously.
we are using below settings on Appsettings.json of Access management. Any changes required on configuration?

```
"ClientSettings": {
    "AccessTokenLifetime": 3600,
    "CacheLifetime": 30,
    "ShowPII": true
  },
  "AccountOptions": {
    "ShowLogoutPrompt": true,
    "AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut": false,
    "IncludeWindowsGroups": false
  },
  "ForwardedHeadersOptions": {
    "ForwardedHeaders": "All",
    "KnownProxies": [],
    "KnownNetworks": []
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Ajay , in normally case it should show the popup screen to enter the user credentials or it should take you to the login page. In your case can we enable the logs to debug you can find it on the appsettings.json and check the access management logs for more details  example : under C:\AccessManagement\bin\logs  . please share the log details and will know what is going on .  I don't think its related to AccessTokenLifetime.

Comment: The title bar in the screenshot shows that your browser is actually redirected to Access Management in order to refresh the token (or sign in again). However, apparently Access Management (or an inbetween proxy) force closed the connection.  Indeed, check the Access Management logs to see if Access Management itself did this and why.  Also check inbetween proxy logs (load balancer, firewall).

Comment: Ajay, As per documentation in following Url,  https://docs.rws.com/816112/785812/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/access-management-configuration-properties, You can update AccessTokenLifetime value in appsettings.json , By doing that we may need to compromise on security, hope that helps